# Why use async await if same can be achieved by Task.run

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Do both methods below behave the same way?  Is there an internal difference as to how they work? Both methods will release the UI thread and continue executing once the delay is over.

```
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test Async start");
        //Any long running operation
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Test Async end");
    }

    public void TestTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test Task start");

        Task.Run(() =>
            {    
                //Any long running operation                
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        ).ContinueWith((prevTask) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Task end");
        });
    }

**output**:
Test Async start
Test Task start
Test Async end
Test Task end
```

Comment: Suppose it is a winforms app, and you want to update the UI instead of `Console.WriteLine("Test Async end");`. Of course that can be implemented without await, but it make the life easier

Comment: First of all, the methods may represent the same behavior, but internally there are many differences between a synchronous `Thread.Sleep` and an asynchronous `Task.Delay`. Also, imagine you wanted to get the result of 3 tasks using `ContinueWith`, the code would be a huge mess

Comment: `Task.Run` uses a new thread from the thread pool while `Task.Delay` does it on the very same thead with a system timer in the background that just *wakes* up the execution engine.

Comment: so mainly its about the ease of use right ? Ignore the task.delay and thread.sleep, that is just for example. Instead of that it can be any long running operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be
>   created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async
>   method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current
>   synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the
>   method is active.

You don't need System.Threading for Tasks.  The code below does because of CancellationToken.

One difference is with Task you have access to properties on the main (UI) thread.

See Quantity.  You can even write to the main thread but probably not a good practice.

```
    async Task<int> TaskDelayAsync(CancellationToken ct, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Quantity);
        int i = 0; 
        while (true)
        {               
            i++;
            //Debug.WriteLine(i);
            progress.Report(i);
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: This is good answer, also found good article about this. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html